# Is there actually a large change in accuracy with Compensated pistols' "+350% Weapon Accuracy"?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

The first chest of Hyperion Station, while grinding against the Legionaries and opening it while Jack's getting beat on the floor, sometimes, I'm seeing some very big numbers in the loot's descriptions, like a Level 2 Compensated Factualizer with:

> +350% Weapon Accuracy
> +148% Weapon Recoil Reduction

Looking at variants listed on the Wiki, it seems confirmed that the Compensated prefix is what's causing it.

I'm not a fan of "Consumes 2 ammo per shot" guns like that, so I don't know if I should have gone for it, instead of tossing it.

Does "+350% Weapon Accuracy" have an effect that matches its large numbers? Like, how much tighter are my groupings, for instance?

Comment: I'm kinda missing the "+8% Crit damage" all the original Hyperion weapons share.
The factualizer uses the hyperion barrel that usually grants this trait.

Comment: @procra - I didn't list all the modifiers, I just listed the ones I care about.

Answer (score 1):

### **Recoil reduction is in general a great trait and often underrated, BUT(T) it kinda messes up the *reverse recoil reduction* of Hyperion weapons.**

The higher accurancy means the maximum accurancy will be approx 100% given to the already top accurancy of Hyperion weapons it will become a pinpointer. But the recoil reduction causes the gun to reach that maximum accurancy much slower as the guns accurancy *increases* based on the recoil. **If recoil gets reduced, the increase of accurancy also gets reduced**, meaning you have to fire longer to get on levels with the gun. Plus Hyperion mag sizes are rather small compared to others and recoil gets applied per shot - not per bullet. So the double shot accessory is more an ammo drainer than useful. It's suitable for Maliwan and/or Torgue and absoluetly gross on Vladof. A "Dva Anarchist" will eat your ammo pool like nothing.

Recommendation: toss it into the grinder, there's better handguns than that. Of the characters in BLTPS there is no Hyperion-focussed class (like Sal, Catalyst Maya or Anarchy Gaige in BL2), maybe except a fragger Claptrap with unpredicable results.